# Django: Does model_instance.clean() run before basic validators?

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

Let's say that I have a model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean(self):
        self.color = self.client.favorite_color
```

When I run this on the latest Django (head of the SVN from 15 minutes ago), if I hit save without selecting a `client`, I get a `DoesNotExist` error from inside my clean method (for the `self.client.favorite_color` part). Since the model requires the `client` attribute, shouldn't this be handled before my custom validation in `clean()`?

Here's the documentation I'm reading: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#id1

Comment: Can you use the clean function on models? I thought it was only for ModelForms?

Comment: @D4V360: The OP is referring to the SVN version. The `clean` method was introduced. See all model methods:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#ref-models-instances

Comment: If you're going to pull down the SVN, pull from revision #12267. In #12268 and forward until they fix it (I put in a ticket), if you raise a ValidationError('with a string like this which is documented'), a run-time error happens in django.forms.models because of a bug. 12268 is where that bug was introduced.

Comment: See http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12698 if you're curious about what orokusaki's talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone runs into this problem:

In full_clean() on the model, first clean_fields() is run, but no errors are raised for display, etc. Instead they are simply added to a dict() and then clean(), which is the custom validation method for your model is run to add any of your custom errors to the dict. Only after that are the errors raised again.

Answer (score -3):

`clean()` is a callable of ModelForms, not models.

[See the docs.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)

To do what you seem to want to do at the Model level, [override the `save()` method.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)

**Edit after comment:** Well, it appears it is time to read the docs all over again with 1.2 impending. :-) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: clean() is a model method now too. Here's a link: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#id1

Comment: @celopes LOL, I know. I would complain but I'm early enough into my project that I'm pulling weekly SVN down and working out bugs as I go because this model validation is something I've always dreamed of and there's more new stuff like queryset.exists(), etc. If you're going to use SVN for this new validation, I'd grab revision #12268.